# How to save POST&GET headers of a web page with "Wireshark"?

Tags: login, wireshark, headers

I've been trying to find a python code that would log in to my mail box on yahoo.com from "Google App Engine". I was given this code:

```
import urllib, urllib2, cookielib

url = "https://login.yahoo.com/config/login?"
form_data = {'login' : 'my-login-here', 'passwd' : 'my-password-here'}

jar = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(jar))
form_data = urllib.urlencode(form_data)
# data returned from this pages contains redirection
resp = opener.open(url, form_data)
# yahoo redirects to http://my.yahoo.com, so lets go there instead
resp = opener.open('http://mail.yahoo.com')
print resp.read()
```

The author of this script looked into HTML script of [yahoo log-in form](https://login.yahoo.com/config/login_verify2?&.src=ym)
and came up with this script.

That log-in form contains two fields, one for users' Yahoo! ID and another one is for users' password.

However, when I tried this code out (substituting mu real Yahoo login for 'my-login-here' and my real password for 'my-password-here'), it just return the log-in form back to me, which means that something didn't work right.

Another supporter suggested that I should send an MD5 hash of my password, rather than a plain password.

He also noted that in that log-in form there are a lot other hidden fields besides login and password fields (he called them "CSRF protections") that I would also have to deal with:

```
<input type="hidden" name=".tries" value="1"> 
<input type="hidden" name=".src" value="ym"> 
<input type="hidden" name=".md5" value=""> 
<input type="hidden" name=".hash" value=""> 
<input type="hidden" name=".js" value=""> 
<input type="hidden" name=".last" value=""> 
<input type="hidden" name="promo" value=""> 
<input type="hidden" name=".intl" value="us"> 
<input type="hidden" name=".bypass" value=""> 
<input type="hidden" name=".partner" value=""> 
<input type="hidden" name=".u" value="bd5tdpd5rf2pg"> 
<input type="hidden" name=".v" value="0"> 
<input type="hidden" name=".challenge" value="5qUiIPGVFzRZ2BHhvtdGXoehfiOj"> 
<input type="hidden" name=".yplus" value=""> 
<input type="hidden" name=".emailCode" value=""> 
<input type="hidden" name="pkg" value=""> 
<input type="hidden" name="stepid" value=""> 
<input type="hidden" name=".ev" value=""> 
<input type="hidden" name="hasMsgr" value="0"> 
<input type="hidden" name=".chkP" value="Y"> 
<input type="hidden" name=".done" value="http://mail.yahoo.com">
```

He said that I should do the following:

1. Simulate normal login and save login page that I get;
2. Save POST&GET headers with "Wireshark";
3. Compare login page with those headers and see what fields I need to include with my request;

I really don't know how to carry out the first two of these three steps. I have just downloaded "Wireshark" and have tried capturing some packets there. However, I don't know how to "simulate normal login and save the login page". Also, I don't how to save POST$GET headers with "Wireshark". Can anyone, please, guide me through these two steps in "Wireshark"? Or at least tell me what I should start with. Thank You.

Comment: Stop reposting this question every other hour.

Comment: random, please take note that all the questions that I have posted so far are different. For example, on SO I asked a question about what a header is, and this present question is about how to use "Wireshark" to get POST&GET headers. This one I have accidentally re-posted only once and wanted to delete the twin as soon as I discovered that, but, alas, moderators saw it earlier than me and deleted it. What makes You think I've been re-posting this question "every other hour"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need Wireshark for this. [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) is perfectly capable of tearing apart requests and responses right from Firefox.

Comment: @ Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: Hello Ignacio!!!! I tried firebug and what I got there was the same list of "input types" that You can see in my question (second vertical blue line on the left side). But, having singled them out, I still have no idea how I should include them in my request and where their correct values are. (I thought "Wireshark" would make it clear to me) Do You have any idea?

Comment: Try the Net panel.

Comment: Is it a piece of software that I should download? Where can I get it?

Comment: Yes. It's called Firebug. I already gave the link for it.

Comment: Ooops! I am sorry!! I didn't notice it there. :( I used "inspect" panel there.

Comment: So, I have just enabled the Net panel, but it doesn't show anything there.

Comment: Ignacio, I am sorry, but I think there is something about "Wireshark" that "Firebug" doesn't have - with the "Firebug" I don't see any Post&Get headers. So, I will reask this question.

Answer (score 1):

When you were asked to

> simulate normal login and save the
>   login page

it was a a request for you to login to your Yahoo account as you would do normally from a Web Browser and save the page.

As for HTTP POST/GET variables & saving them, I don't have experience but you should probably have a look at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604888/what-is-a-header-especially-what-are-postget-headers/2604909#2604909)

---

Seems you're the OP for the Q in SO -.-

Comment: @ Sathya: I see, Sathya, thank You for this input.

Comment: Yes, Sathya, that's me there - I am doing all things possible to understand this matter. Anyway, thank You for explaining to me what that supporter meant by "simulate". As a non-English speaker, I had a hard time to catch his meaning behind that word.